# Bash: removing several patterns from file names

Tags: bash, pattern-matching, basename

Normally, looping over the files I use `basename` to extract the name of the file as a separate variable:

```
# remove .pdb extension from filename in new variable and print name of the file without it
for pdb in "${storage}"/complex*.pdb ; do
pdb_name=$(basename "$pdb" .pdb)
echo this is "$pdb_name" without its extension!
done
```

How could I remove several patterns from each file using the same `basename` expression? For instance, in addition to ".pdb" I would like to omit also "complex", which is always present at the beginning of each file (here I used it as a pattern to recognize file in for LOOP).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, `basename` can not remove a prefix from the non-directory portion of a path. I would suggest using parameter expansion features instead:

```bsh
shopt -s nullglob   # Don't loop over the pattern if it matches nothing
for pdb in "$storage"/complex*.pdb
do
  pdb_name=${pdb##*/complex}
  pdb_name=${pdb_name%.pdb}
  printf '%s\n' "$pdb_name"
done
```

`${pdb##*/complex}` expands to the value of `pdb` with the longest prefix that matches the `*/complex` shell pattern removed.

`${pdb_name%.pdb}` expands to the value of `pdb_name` with the shortest suffix matching the `.pdb` shell pattern removed.

While this is not an issue in your case, note that `base_name=$(basename "$path")` strips newline characters at the end of file names (because of command substitution) as a likely unwanted side effect. Shell parameter expansion is safer in this respect.

Comment: thank you! as I understood correclt it is not possible to do those two editions in one basename command, isn't it ?

Comment: As far as I know, no, `basename` can't remove a prefix from the last component of a path.